# Visual Studio, WinForms issue CSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I am stuck at one point.

I have one button which search and execute the path / .exe

But problem is that there is 1% of people in my company which doesn't have this software installed and if they click on it, they get error Couldn't not find the specific folder  file.

How can edit code IF(error) then continue and show MSG. "You don't have this application installed" ?

CODE:

```
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxxxx\xxxx.vbs");
            
        }
```

Error: is in screenshot
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rckUw.png)

Comment: So... [Exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use exception handling:

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxxxx\xxxx.vbs");
}
catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You don't have this application installed");
}
```

Comment: Catch is not recognised

Comment: Please change the code: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex

Comment: do i need to input using system....: for this "Catch"?

Comment: Yes, the opening curly brace is missing before the try statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition to this if the file exists, execute it else do something else, like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

var path = "Path to your File";

if(File.Exists(path))
{
  Process.Start(path);
}
else
{
  //do sth else
}
```